# Unable to set umask for Ansible tasks

Tags: linux, ansible, umask

I'm trying to run an arbitrary Ansible module with a specific `umask` (0002).

Some Ansible modules (like `git`) support a `umask` parameter (or a `mode` parameter to set permissions directly), but many do not.
To my knowledge, Ansible does not invoke a shell (unless you use the `shell` module), so changing the umask in my shell profile is useless.
My approach was to change the `UMASK` line in `/etc/login.defs`, but that didn't make a difference to Ansible. The `umask` remains at 0022.
PAM seems to be configured to include `pam_umask.so`.

I know I could use the `shell` module as a workaround (`shell: umask 0002; some_command`) but that seems like an ugly hack.

**How do I get Ansible to respect my `umask`?**

This is Ansible 2.9.9 targeting a CentOS 8 System.

Comment: There is not reason why this would not work. If it does not work is not because of Ansible.

Comment: In case you are running Ansible locally, did you remember to logout and login again after changing `/etc/login.defs`? You might also have to enable the `pam_umask.so` PAM module. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220531

Comment: Good point, but in this case Ansible was targeting a remote system

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change the umask for the remote host(s), the simplest way is to edit the `~/.bash_profile` of the `remote_user` to have for instance:

```bash
umask 0002
```

To use that setting you'll need to change [executable](https://docs.ansible.com/archive/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#executable) in your **ansible,cfg**, or use `ansible_shell_executable` in your **inventory**:

```ini
[demo]
example.com ansible_shell_executable='/bin/bash -l'
```

**Why this works?** The `-l` argument forces bash to behave as a login shell, sourcing the profile.

**Verification** Use the verbosity `-vvv` when running ansible or ansible-playbook, you'll see that any Ansible module is running form the `executable` with argument `-l` (and `-c` added), you'll see something like:

```
EXEC /bin/bash -l -c '/usr/libexec/platform-python /home/demo/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1706875415.3499873-5842-271431387344170/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'
```

Comment: Hey, many thanks for paying attention to such an old question!  
While this would probably work out, I'm wondering how to do this without invoking umask from a particular shell's (or even ssh) config.  
There has to be a way to set a default umask somewhere deeper in the stack?  
I thought `pam_umask` would be the way to go, but couldn't get that to do anything.

Comment: My later answer on this question is more elegant.


The pam_umask module tries to get the umask value from the following places in the following order:
      ·   umask= entry in the user's GECOS field
       ·   umask= argument
       ·   UMASK entry from /etc/login.defs
       ·   UMASK= entry from /etc/default/login

Comment: While your later answer would indeed be preferable, I'm still searching for a way to do this without involving shell or ssh config. As you can see in the original question, I already tried to modify `/etc/login.defs`. Maybe I did something wrong there, maybe some of the other possibilities you mentioned might help.
It will take me some time to tinker with that, as I'm busy with other stuff at the moment unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The SSH rc file `~/.ssh/rc` is much like a shell startup file (e.g., `~/.bash_profile`), but it executes only when your account is accessed by SSH. It is run for both interactive logins and remote commands. Place any commands in this script that you would like executed when your account is accessed by SSH, rather than an ordinary login.

You need `PermitUserRC yes` in /etc/sshd_config, but that is the default for OpenSSH.